# Select single node with same attribute name in .NET 2.0

Tags: xml, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

My xml looks like

```
<article>
    <article-id pub-id-type="local">ABC</article-id>
    <article-id pub-id-type="external">XYZ</article-id>
</article>
```

I can do the following

```
dim articleId as string =  doc.SelectSingleNode("./article/article-id", nsm).InnerText
```

and the result is ABC

I don't know how to get the result to be XYZ - I assume because I'm using SelectSingleNode it is getting the First item. Is there a way to tell it to get the second?

Please note, although I've shown an example with only 2 nodes, there could be any number so it must be 'searchable' by the name 'external'

I've not really used .NET 2.0 before and the MSDN didn't really help me.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath:

```
"./article/article-id[@pub-id-type='external']"
```

The `[@pub-id-type='external']` is an attribute filter.

If you have multiple possible elements, you could add `[last()]` to get the last of them.

For more XPath info, check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).

Comment: Although this probably would suffice, I'm afraid to mention that on occasions I may have any number of nodes - therefore it would have to be node specific (by name). (I have updated my question. Sorry) +1

Comment: ha ha, I was going to ask if the @ symbol had any relevance. Perfect,  thank you

Comment: You're welcome! XPath is actually really flexible at times, and can be a lot more succinct than LINQ2XML.